# Is multiple named query file possible

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I always see a single file being used for named query. I have never seen multiple file for queries, but can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can add as many as you want.

It's actually a mapping file, but hibernate doesn't care if there isn't a class mapping definition in there.
See the docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-xmlconfig), so you should add a

```
<mapping resource="path/to/your/Mapping-or-query-file.hbm.xml"/>
```